# Invalid identifier ' '. Apex identifiers must start with an ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by any number of ASCII letters

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I get this error while writing apex trigger.

```
    trigger OppUpdateFromAccount on Account (before insert) {
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Account a:Trigger.new){
            accountIds.add(a.Id);
        }
        //day30 is the date which is 30 days less than today
        DateTime day30=system.now()-30;
        List<Opportunity> oppListToUpdate=new List<Opportunity>();
        //getting the opportunities whose account has been updated
        List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select Id, AccountId, StageName, CreatedDate, CloseDate from Opportunity where AccountId in :accountIds];
        if(oppList.size()>0){
            for(Opportunity opp : oppList){
                //checking for condition if created date is greater than 30 days from today and stage not equal to close won
                if(opp.CreatedDate<day30 && opp.StageName!='Closed Won'){
                    opp.StageName ='Closed Lost';    //This is a mandatory field when we update the CloseDate
                    opp.CloseDate = system.today();
                    oppListToUpdate.add(opp);  //putting the changed opportunity to separate list to update later
                }
            }
        }
    //checking if the opportunity list which has changed is having records or not
    if(oppListToUpdate.size()>0){
        update oppListToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see any error in the trigger except '} 'was missing at the end. Can you try to create a new trigger and check.

Comment: yeah I'm Also not getting what was the actual error, I tried this code with another org also. but I got same error at `opp.StageName ='Closed Lost'; ` and `oppListToUpdate.add(opp);`

Comment: @VimalPandit, as pointed out by SaiPraveen it looks like you simply forgot a closing curly bracket in the end. Not true? In that case, could you please correct the code presented in your question?

Comment: I tried creating the same trigger with extra } at the last and it saved successfully. Can you confirm how are you creating the trigger ?

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to add upate list line of code in question. But I tried it in every way that i know. but getting error.

Comment: Did you try creating directly from the Object manager triggers section by clicking on new and remove the entire content there and just copy paste the above code?

Comment: No I tried it with my VsCode and also tried it in Console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues like these tend to be caused by invisible/non-printable characters. The invisible nature of these characters makes it hard to detect, and carries over when you copy/paste code.

The easiest way to deal with this issue (if it is the issue) is to simply re-type the entire trigger (or class). If your error specifies a line number, you may be able to get away with only re-typing that individual line. At any rate, the important part here is that *you should not use copy/paste* for *anything* when trying to fix this type of issue.